# How to store most recent file path as a variable and then read it in python

Tags: python, xml, file, path

Disclaimer: I am very new to Python but I love to jump in to a project.

What I am trying to do is search a folder for each element in my tuple and for each element, open the most recent file (which is an xml file). Then search that file for the strings failed and passed. And then return either true or false if the file contained more than 2 of either failed/passed.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to open the most recent file after python finds it with the new_file_path variable.
I get: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'newest_file_path'

```
import os
import glob
KeyWord = ("failed", "passed")
SNtup = ('5241', '4784', '4698')
TestResults = 'C:/Users/blah/blah'
for i in os.listdir(TestResults):
for x in SNtup:
        # glob.glob returns all paths matching the pattern.
        TestResults = list(glob.glob(os.path.join(TestResults, '*.XML*')))
        mod_dates = [os.path.getmtime(f) for f in TestResults]
        #sort by mod_dates.
        file_date = sorted(zip(TestResults, mod_dates), key=lambda d: d[1])
        newest_file_path = file_date[0][1]
        with open('newest_file_path') as p:
            file_content = p.read()
            for y in KeyWord:
                if y > 2 in file_content:
                    print('True')
                else:
                    print('False')
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're passing the string, `'newest_file_path'`, instead of the variable, and also grabbing the date rather than the path. Try like this:

```
...
        newest_file_path = file_date[0][0]
        with open(newest_file_path) as p:
...
```

Because `zip(TestResults, mod_dates)` puts the directories as the 0th index, and the dates as the 1st index.